# Python scipy.signal.wiener filter for speech processing

Tags: filters, speech-processing, wiener-filter

As far as I know Wiener filter can be used in Image processing.I wonder that if i can use Python scipy.signal.wiener() for speech processing as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Yes, the function can operate over a 1 dimensional signal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.wiener.html) (?)

Comment: @A_A: Why not to make it an answer? ;)

Comment: @jojek I did not think it qualifies even as a short answer :) Merely pointing out the documentation, but if more information was provided I might attempt one.

Comment: @A_A: Just trying to avoid unanswered questions popping back to the main page. Should you wish, we can close it.

Comment: @jojek Thank you for letting me know. I think that as a pointer to the documentation, it would not add a great deal of value. I have voted for closing the question too. If the OP does not come back with more clarification, I think it is reasonable to put it on hold or close it.